# How to add remote issue link in jira-rest-api

Tags: jira-rest-api

I've got a program which creates JIRA issues using the jira-rest-api supported by Atlassian.

What I'd like to do is to create a link within the issue to an external URL (actually a presigned Amazon S3 link).

At the REST level this should be doable with a POST request to the Jira api to create a remoteLink. However I cannot find methods in the client APIs or a RemoteLink dto in the Java library.

Nor does the Java library appear to give any access to lower level REST handlers.

Now, I could set up my own REST handling code, going right back to the endpoint URL and authentication, but that's messy, when most of the code the code should already be there. Also I can't clearly see which json fields are required, and which not can be left to the API.

Am I overlooking something obvious in the documentation? I can't even seem to locate source for the client implementation, only the interface layer.

My current code is using version 3.0.6 of the api, but I've just checked v4 (which seems to be the latest on offer) and there's still no RemoteLink support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with these?

Server: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/?_ga=2.26380925.1321063199.1523351418-1788196903.1491202928#api/2/issue-deleteRemoteIssueLinkById

Cloud: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-remotelink-linkId-delete

Comment: I understand that I could do it with a raw REST transaction. However the rest of my issue construction I'm doing through the Java API library, which is taking care of credentials, endpoints etc.. I would either have to do my own REST calls for everything, or use two sets of call environment stuff because the core classes of the API library don't expose any low level access to make customised calls.